# VSCodeでDockerコンテナにリモート接続した際、codeコマンドが動作しない

Tags: docker, vscode, ssh

リモートサーバー内のDockerコンテナに、ローカルPCのVSCodeで接続(Remote - SSHとRemote - containersのExtensionsを使用)しておりますが、VSCodeのターミナル(Bash)上で

```
$ code <file name>
```

と打ち込んでも

```
bash: code: command not found
```

というエラーメッセージが出力されて、VSCode上でファイルの編集をすることが出来ません。

VSCodeのエクスプローラー(Ctrl+Shift+E)から、ファイルをクリックすれば編集画面は表示されるのですが、`code`コマンドで呼び出すことは出来ないものでしょうか?

また、コマンドパレット(Ctrl+Shift+P)を呼び出してから、`Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH`で検索しても一致するコマンドは見つかりませんでした。

実行環境は下記の通りです：

- ローカルPC：Windows10 Pro
- リモート先のホストPC：Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- リモート先のホストPC内のDockerコンテナ：Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

ご回答、何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リモート先のコンテナ内で、`code`コマンドを使ってVSCodeを呼び出すことができたので自己回答します。

ホーム直下をよく探してみると、

```
$HOME/.vscode-server/bin/<directory with a hash-like name>/bin/
```

に`code`があったので、これにPATHを通すとうまくいきました。
ちなみに、`<directory with a hash-like name>`とはハッシュっぽい名前のディレクトリで、
これはコンテナにリモート接続時に自動的にランダムでつけられるディレクトリです。
毎回違うので、各自で参照してみて下さい。

一応Pathの通し方は下記の通りです。

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.vscode-server/bin/<directory with a hash-like name>/bin/"
```

`~/.bashrc`の最後の行にこれを記述して、

```
$source ~/.bashrc
```

としてもいいと思います。

何卒宜しくお願いいたします。